# MySQL in PHP: prepare and execute query with variable and LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql, variables, prepared-statement

I am trying to create a MySQL query with a variable LIMIT value to display Table results on multiple pages.
This doesn't work:

```
// Check the page number
if (isset($_GET["usPage"])) { 
    $treatedPage  = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_GET["usPage"])); 
} else { 
    $treatedPage=1; 
}
$start_from = ($treatedPage-1) * 20; 
// Prepare MySQL query with a variable depending on page to display
$req = $DB->prepare('SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY Id ASC LIMIT :MySQL_start_from, 20');
$req->execute(array(
    'MySQL_start_from' => $start_from
    ));
// Fetch result and display array content
$row = $req->fetch();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($row);
echo '</pre>';
```

If I replace :MySQL_start_from by 0, I can display row content. I think my problem comes from that variable in the query. Any error noticed?

Comment: you mean you want to set pagination ?

Comment: why are you using `mysql_real_escape_string` **and** PDO? it's not needed. Also, for that calculation, cast it to int first and if that fails set it to 1...

Comment: @ Devang Rathod: Indeed, if you've a better solution, go ahead. But even if there is a best way to do it, I'm interested by understanding why my code doesn't work here... ;-)
@Hiroto: Yes, it is a better solution, I will think of it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either set your PDO into non-emulation mode

```
$DB->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
```

or bind your variable explicitly setting it's type to integer using `bindValue`

when binding variables right from execute PDO treats them as strings and thus your query looks like `ORDER BY Id ASC LIMIT '0', 20')` and causes parse error.

By the way, to be notified of these errors always tell PDO to throw an exception:

```
$DB->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

of course you have to get rid of both `mysql_real_escape_string` and `strip_tags`, as they are useless here.

So the final code would be

```
//  right after $DB = new PDO...
$DB->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$DB->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);

// and then with your code
if (isset($_GET["usPage"])) { 
    $treatedPage  = $_GET["usPage"]; 
} else { 
    $treatedPage=1; 
}
$start_from = ($treatedPage-1) * 20; 
// Prepare MySQL query with a variable depending on page to display
$req = $DB->prepare('SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY Id ASC LIMIT ?, 20');
$req->execute(array($start_from));
// Fetch result and display array content
$row = $req->fetch();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($row);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try it by tomorrow and get information about the setAttribute function which seems important. Thanks anyway!
About mysql_real_escape_string and strip_tags, shouldn't I protect the usPage variable from code injection via the URL?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use in the belwo way:

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY :sort :dir LIMIT :start, :results";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':start', $_GET['start'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':results', $_GET['results'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: what is the issue with this